# Struts2, Hibernate - Stale data

Tags: hibernate

This is my action:

```
public class TestPollAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2753118140091192432L;

    public String execute() {
        String temp = "start";
        while(!"accepted".equals(temp)) {
            temp = getJobStatus("2");
            System.out.println("temp: " + temp);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }   

public static String getJobStatus(String jobId) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        String jobStatus = null;
        JobBoard jobBoard = null;
        try {
            jobBoard = (JobBoard) session.createQuery("from " + JobBoard.class.getSimpleName() + " where jobId = :jobId )").setParameter("jobId", jobId).uniqueResult();
            jobStatus = jobBoard.getStatus();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();            
        }       
        return jobStatus;
    }
}
```

I am calling this action from postman. Then using MySQL Workbench, I am updating the database, setting the status field to "accepted" and then clicking "Apply" which commits the changes to the database.

But that `System.out.println("temp: " + temp);` does not show me the updated value, it keeps showing me "start".

Comment: You can't see changes from the same action. You should use another action for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the one that should be used. I had a different dependency.